# How to check the status of Platform Developer I Certification Maintenance (Summer '18) completion

Tags: certification, summer-18

Can anybody answer my question I have received a mail stating that I have to complete the maintenance exam for salesforce with link to Trailhead. I have completed the Platform Developer I Certification Maintenance (Summer '18) quiz in trailhead. Is that the only exam I have to appear for to maintain the certificate?
How can I check the status that I have completed the exam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to [Trailhead Verification link](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/credentials/verification) and select Certification Holders: Check Your status by entering your email and then Request. Complete the captcha and you will get an email listing your all certifications and their status. This will have a subject of 'Your credential status' as below.

It takes some time for the updates to show, as I found that I didn't see the exam completion till the next day.

[image: Verification site]

[image]

Comment: Does it take time to reflect the status?? I have completed the exam about 2 hours ago

Comment: When I did mine it seemed to be overnight, I'll edit that into the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I definitely agree with the other answers posted that going to the [Trailhead verification link](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/credentials/verification) and submitting your email will verify your status. Something to be mindful of is that you need to make sure your [Trailhead and Webassessor accounts are linked](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help?article=Link-Your-Trailhead-and-Webassessor-Accounts). You can verify this from the same email and there is [more information here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help?article=Credential-Status-Request-Overview) regarding the actual status verification email.

Nonetheless, after doing exactly this, I found that even after doing the maintenance quiz on Trailhead, and verifying my accounts were linked, my status still did not update. I was only able to solve the problem by [submitting a support request](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help?support=article&article=Credential-Status-Request-Overview#) stating that I had verified that my accounts were linked and that I have completed the maintenance trail but was not seeing this reflected in my status verification. Trailhead support were then able to fix this on their end.

Comment: I agree with you I have linked my trailhead account with webassessor account as well as completed the quiz in trailhead still I cannot find the status as completed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have completed [Platform Developer I Certification Maintenance (Summer '18)](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/platform_dev_i_cert_maint_sum18) module you can check your certification status using [Verify Credentials](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/credentials/verification). Provide your trailhead email id and request. Status will be send to your mail id.